# Finding principal components with maximum variance in matlab

Tags: matlab, pca, svd

I used the following code to compute PCA :

```
    function [signals,PC,V] = pca2(data) 
    [M,N] = size(data); 
    % subtract off the mean for each dimension 
    mn = mean(data,2); 
    data = data - repmat(mn,1,N); 
    % construct the matrix Y 
    Y = data’ / sqrt(N-1); 
    % SVD does it all 
    [u,S,PC] = svd(Y); 
    % calculate the variances 
    S = diag(S); 
    V = S .* S; 
    % project the original data 
    signals = PC’ * data;
```

I want to keep the principal components with the maximum variance , say maybe the first 10 principal components which contribute to the maximum variance. How do i go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function [signals,V] = pca2(data) 
    [M,N] = size(data); 
    data = reshape(data, M*N,1);
    % subtract off the mean for each dimension 
    mn = mean(data,2); 
    data = bsxfun(@minus, data, mean(data,1));     
    % construct the matrix Y 
    Y = data'*data / (M*N-1); 
    [V D] = eigs(Y, 10);   % reduce to 10 dimension
    % project the original data 
    signals = data * V;
```

Comment: Lennon i had tried this out but the line Y = data'*data / (N-1); gave an error. I will check it again and get back to you with the exact error.

Comment: Sid, your data is supposed to be a vector. If it is not, use data=reshape(data,M*N,1);  see my update in answer, thanks

Comment: Lennon, it worked. To subtract the mean i used :                      mn = mean(data,2); 
data = data - repmat(mn,1,N);

Comment: I have another doubt though, from this function i get two outputs 'signals' and 'V'. size(signals)=65536*10 and size(V)=21*10. Could you please explain to me what the outputs exactly mean? I know that 'V' is the eigenspace/new coordinates & 'signals' are the projections of the data into the eigenspace/new coordinates. Is this right?

Comment: And for training i am using "signals" (having a size of 65536*10) and not "V" to train the classifier. Is that ok?

Comment: Sid. You understanding is correct. V is the eigenvectors corresponding to the 1st 10 eigenvalues, and signals is the projection of data on V. When you are training, you use signals instead of V. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much that really makes it all very clear.

Comment: :If you could help me out with the following question too i would be really thankful. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20998789/how-to-overcome-dimension-mismatch-for-writing-to-a-csv-file-in-matlab

Comment: I used the 'signals' to train svm classifier but it's showing the predicted label as -1 even though it should be +1. I am using pca to find the features of both training and testing data. Any help will be really helpful.

Comment: i was just wondering what were you doing these days by switching the acceptance for various questions?

Comment: i am sorry i just realised i can accept not more than one answer :/ !

Comment: it would be really helpful if you answered this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474331/why-is-the-accuracy-coming-as-0-matlab-libsvm/21541808?noredirect=1#comment32541358_21541808

Answer (score 1):

I guess [svds](http://www.mathworks.cn/cn/help/matlab/ref/svds.html) can do the job for you.

In the doc, it says:

> s = svds(A,k) computes the k largest singular values and associated
>   singular vectors of matrix A.

Which is essentially the k largest eigenvalues and eigenvectors. These are sorted by eigenvalues in descending order.

So for 10 principal components, just use `[eigvec eigval] = svds(Y, 10);`