# How to overcome dimension mismatch for writing to a CSV file in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, csv

I have calculated features of an image which is a 4*4 matrix. I extract these features for 21 images(same person but 21 different poses) . I now want to store these features into a CSV file with labels +1. I try to do that using

```
features=ctsfeatures(inputdata); %inputdata is an array of 21 images                                                                                              
for i=1:length(features)                                                
   for j=1:1
       label(i,j)=+1;
   end
end

csvwrite('fea.csv',[label features]);
```

But i get the following error:

```
Horzcat dimension mismatch in line csvwrite('fea.csv',[label features]);
```

Please tell me how to overcome this error.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to make sure that `label` and `features` have the same dimensions along the dimension you want to concatenate. What are the dimensions of `label` and `features`?

Comment: features has a dimension of 21*1. And since i have run a loop for the size of label it should come up to the same as features and it does i.e 21*1.

Comment: Then what is the `4x4` matrix you reference?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your error. Just double check size(label) and size(features) before csvwrite, making sure they are the same.

Comment: The syntax you use in the label change is very strange. I would recommend either `label(i,j)=1` (does what you currently do) or perhaps `label(i,j)=label(i,j)+1` (adds 1 to the relevant element)

Comment: @Lennon : Ya there is something amiss with the size. I will double check it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your features is of size `4*4`, you need to have label of size `4*4`

```
features=ctsfeatures(inputdata); %inputdata is an array of 21 images                                                                                              
for i=1:size(features,1)                                                
   for j=1:size(features,2)
      label(i,j)=+1;
   end
end

csvwrite('fea.csv',[label features]);
```

Comment: Note that this double for loop could probably be reduced to: `label(1:size(features,1) ,1:size(features,2)) = 1`

Comment: @Lokesh , Dennis : I will try this and get back with the results. Thanks